# How to document object literals in ESDOC

Tags: javascript, esdoc

The documentation doesn't mention it.

https://esdoc.org/manual/usage/tags.html

Anyone knows how to document object literals in ESDoc and generate a report that describes the object with all the methods and values. Would like to know how to document the following markup.

```
/**
 * @??
 */
export default {
  /**
   * @??
   */ 
  myProperty: 1,
  /**
   * @??
   */
  myFunction: () => {}
}
```

Comment: Added the issue to GitHub @ https://github.com/esdoc/esdoc/issues/419.